# how do you install php-devel

Tags: linux, centos, php, ssh, yum

I keep getting dependency issues when I try to run `yum install php-devel`

yum install --skip-broken php-devel

```
....
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-32.el5 is needed by package php-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 (base)
php-cli-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-32.el5 is needed by package php-cli-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 (base)
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.i386 0:5.1.6-32.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-32.el5 for package: php-devel
---> Package php-cli.i386 0:5.1.6-32.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-devel-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-32.el5 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 (base)

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    autoconf-2.59-12.noarch from base
    automake-1.9.6-2.3.el5.noarch from base
    imake-1.0.2-3.i386 from base
    php-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 from base
    php-cli-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 from base
    php-devel-5.1.6-32.el5.i386 from base
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you want to install the dependancies? yum shows you what dependancies you need for the installation. otherwise you might as well just use a .rpm if you just want this one package.

Comment: are the dependencies I need the ones at the bottom?

Comment: no they are the packages skipped. the one you seem to need is php-common.  try yum install php-devel and then it will suggest an an option of what it needs to do to install. (leave out the skip-broken

Comment: I already have php-common. http://screensnapr.com/v/ArwVW2.jpg

Comment: that list at the bottom is everything that has not been able to be installed and is needed for php-devel. if you do yum install php-devel then it should install everything you need for it to work.

Comment: It tells me that I need php-common, but I already have that installed.

Answer (score 0):

as per error message - you are missing php-common package to satisfy yum installer. You might want to try to clean your cache (yum clean all) and re-run yum install php-devel command.

Perhaps repo which provides php-common is disabled? (yum repolist all)?

**Update**

Also make sure that you are installing for the right arch... uname -r. 
To force package installation for specific arch you can: yum install php-devel.x86_64

Comment: I did what you advised, but still the same dep errors. http://screensnapr.com/v/Q6528a.jpg